# Display nested JS array by group to HTML from JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I'm calling data from an API which returns blog post information. I've taken the data and sorted it into an array by month. I seem to be able to print out the information to the console, but have trouble actually displaying this info to HTML. I run down this rabbit hole of loops.

I'd like each post to display in it's own div. For example, all January posts are in their own div, February is in another, etc.

Here is an example of the original [JSON Data](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2). CTRL + F and type "Text Posts"

I'm using ajax to call the API

```
  //...

  $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{blog}.com/posts/text?api_key={APIKey}",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data){

    let groupByMonth = Object.create(null);
    var objectPosts = data.response.posts;

    $.each(objectPosts, function(key, value) {

      let getTitle = objectPosts[key].title
      let getDescription = objectPosts[key].body
      let getDate = objectPosts[key].date

      let getMonth = getDate.split('-')[1]

      if (!groupByMonth[getMonth]) {
        groupByMonth[getMonth] = [];
      }

      groupByMonth[getMonth].push({
        Title: getTitle,
        Description: getDescription,
        DatePublished: getDate
      });

    });

    let byMonth =
      Object.entries(groupByMonth)
        .map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}));

    console.log(byMonth);

    // The Tricky Part 
    $.each(byMonth, function(key, value) {
      var outer = byMonth[key]

      $.each(outer, function(k, v) {
        var inner = outer[k]

        var jData = JSON.stringify(v);

        $('<div class = "month"> </div>').appendTo('#blog-posts')

        $.each(inner, function(i, obj) {

          var title = inner[i].Title
          var description = inner[i].Description
          var date = inner[i].DatePublished

          $('<div class = "post"><h2>' + title + '</h2><p>'
              + description + '</p>').appendTo('.month')

        })         
    }
```

I've used dummy data for the output.

`console.log(byMonth)` returns a nested JS array

```
0:
  11:
    0: {Title: "Sample Title", Description: "Sample Desc", DatePublished: "2016-11-29 16:23:35 GMT"}
    1: {Title: "Sample Title", Description: "Sample Desc", DatePublished: "2016-11-29 16:23:35 GMT"}
    2: {Title: "Sample Title", Description: "Sample Desc", DatePublished: "2016-11-29 16:23:35 GMT"}

1:
  09: 
    0: {Title: "Sample Title", Description: "Sample Desc", DatePublished: "2016-09-22 12:34:40 GMT"}

2:
  08:
    0: {Title: "Sample Title", Description: "Sample Desc", DatePublished: "2016-08-29 16:23:35 GMT"}
    1: {Title: "Sample Title", Description: "Sample Desc", DatePublished: "2016-08-29 16:23:35 GMT"}
```

`11` indicates the month of November, `09` is September, etc.

`console.log(jData)` returns the data of the respective month

```
[{Title: "Sample Title", Description: "Sample Desc", DatePublished: "2016-11-29 16:23:35 GMT"},{Title: "Sample Title", Description: "Sample Desc", DatePublished: "2016-11-29 16:23:35 GMT"},{Title: "Sample Title", Description: "Sample Desc", DatePublished: "2016-11-29 16:23:35 GMT"}] 
[{Title: "Sample Title", Description: "Sample Desc", DatePublished: "2016-09-22 12:34:40 GMT"}]
[{Title: "Sample Title", Description: "Sample Desc", DatePublished: "2016-08-29 16:23:35 GMT"},{Title: "Sample Title", Description: "Sample Desc", DatePublished: "2016-08-29 16:23:35 GMT"}]
```

I feel close to the solution, but I'm stuck with actually outputting the info to HTML. After appending the `title` and `description` to `<div class = "month">`, each div contains all titles and descriptions from all months, instead of their own month. I've tried `for` loops as well with no luck. Solution is probably simple. Thanks in advance!

Comment: how to figure out which div is for which month? is it index-based?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution, you will end up with multiple `<div class="month"/>` elements, and data will be appended to all of them.

To fix: in the outer loop, obtain a reference to the month element you have appended, and then use that in the inner loop to append to.

```
var blogPosts = $('#blog-posts'); // get reference once to avoid repeat lookups

$.each(byMonth, function(key, value) {
  var outer = byMonth[key]

  $.each(outer, function(k, v) {
    var inner = outer[k];

    var jData = JSON.stringify(v);

    var monthBlogPosts = $('<div class = "month"> </div>').appendTo(blogPosts);
    //  ^ obtain reference here 

    $.each(inner, function(i, obj) {
      var title = inner[i].Title;
      var description = inner[i].Description;
      var date = inner[i].DatePublished;

      $('<div class = "post"><h2>' + title + '</h2><p>'
          + description + '</p>').appendTo(monthBlogPosts);
      //                                   ^ use reference here
    })         
}
```